# Android step-counter as a service

Tags: android, android-sensors

Hi currently in my app I am getting the steps count from google fit. But now I want to make it as a service using the device sensors not google fit. Can someone suggest me some useful links to make step-counter as a service. I have found some links on GitHub but they are not working at all.
I found the below links:

https://github.com/itkovian/StepCounter

https://github.com/theelfismike/android-step-counter